# Making a signed HTTP request to AWS Elasticsearch in Python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, boto3

I'm trying to make a simple Python Lambda that makes snapshots of our Elasticsearch database. This is done through [Elasticsearch's REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) using simple HTTP requests.

However, for AWS, I have to sign these requests. I have a feeling it can be achieved through `boto3`'s low-level clients probably with `generate_presigned_url`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to invoke this function correctly. For example, what are the valid `ClientMethod`s? I've tried `ESHttpGet` but to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ok did some digging. Don't think `generate_presigned_url` is the way to go. I think the only operations available to me are high-level ES operations listed in the docs: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/es.html#ElasticsearchService.Client.generate_presigned_url

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several Python extensions to the requests library that will perform the SigV4 signing for you.  I have used [this one](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) and it works well.

Comment: Yeah, I'd been hoping to keep it to just `boto3` and `botocore`, but I've wound up using the `AWSAuthConnection` in `boto` - seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 19):

**Edit: Apparently this workaround has been [broken by Elastic](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/853#issuecomment-897082997).**

I struggled for a while to do a similar thing. Currently the boto3 library doesn't support making signed es requests, though since I [raised an issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/853) with them it's become a feature request.

Here's what I've done in the meantime using [DavidMuller's library](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) mentioned above and boto3 to get my STS session credentials:

```
import boto3
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

es_host = 'search-my-es-domain.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com'
awsauth = AWSRequestsAuth(
    aws_access_key=credentials.access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
    aws_token=credentials.token,
    aws_host=es_host,
    aws_region=session.region_name,
    aws_service='es'
)

# use the requests connection_class and pass in our custom auth class
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': es_host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)

print(es.info())
```

Hope this saves somebody some time.

Answer (score 11):

While other answers are perfectly fine, I wanted to eliminate the use of external packages. Obviously, `botocore` itself has all the required functionality to sign requests it was just a matter of looking at the source code. This is what I ended up with for sending AWS API requests directly (things are hardcoded for the demonstration purposes):

```
      import boto3
      import botocore.credentials
      from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest
      from botocore.endpoint import URLLib3Session
      from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth

      params = '{"name": "hello"}'
      headers = {
        'Host': 'ram.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
      }
      request = AWSRequest(method="POST", url="https://ram.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/createresourceshare", data=params, headers=headers)
      SigV4Auth(boto3.Session().get_credentials(), "ram", "ap-southeast-2").add_auth(request)    


      session = URLLib3Session()
      r = session.send(request.prepare())
```

Comment: `BotocoreHTTPSession` causes an `ImportError` on recent versions of `boto3` (1.9.42 at time of writing). Changing that line to the following resolves the error for me:

`from botocore.httpsession import URLLib3Session`

Answer (score 4):

I recently published [requests-aws-sign](https://github.com/jmenga/requests-aws-sign), which provides AWS V4 request signing for the Python requests library.

If you look at [this code](https://github.com/jmenga/requests-aws-sign/blob/master/requests_aws_sign/requests_aws_sign.py) you will see how you can use Botocore to generate the V4 request signing.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use requests?

```
import requests
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
data = '{"director": "Burton, Tim", "genre": ["Comedy","Sci-Fi","R-rated"],"profit" : 98 , "year": 1996, "actor": ["Jack Nicholson","PierceBrosnan","Sarah Jessica Parker"], "title": "Mars Attacks!"}'
response = requests.post('https://search-your-awsendpoint.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/yourindex/_yourdoc/', headers=headers, data=data)
```

this worked for me

Comment: This implies your endpoint allows public access or (hopefully) is hidden behind a VPC. [The docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html) "If your domain access policy includes IAM users or roles, you must sign requests to the Elasticsearch APIs."

Comment: i am calling this using lambda and yes its a public facing. if you want it inside a vpc ,you can create lambda inside vpc and attach iam role to the lambda. that was my use case.

Comment: so it's public-facing and you allow anyone to put data in it?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html   please follow that document. eventhough it is public facing i can restrict the requests based on either iam permissions or ip address . thanks

Comment: There are still cases where you will need signed requests regardless of resource policies, vpc security groups or iam permissions, such as manual snapshotting.